# DB2 SQL considers IF ELSE condition a DDL statement?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to use a simple IF ELSE query to test a feature with DB2 SQL. However when I attempt to execute it, I run into an error stating that I am not allowed to execute DDL statements.

What is throwing me off is that as far as I know, only database structure altering statements are considered DDL statements.

What gives?

Code:

```
IF 'True' = 'True' THEN
  SELECT * FROM RM_TRANSACTION 
  FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY 
  FOR READ ONLY WITH UR
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM RM_TRANSACTION 
  FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY 
  FOR READ ONLY WITH UR
END IF
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTidT.jpg

Comment: The manual says you need to use `THEN` and `END IF`.  If in doubt, read the ... manual?   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053871.html

Comment: Edited. However that does not solve the issue. I still receive the same errors.

Comment: Edit your post with the exact query you're now using and the full error message.  People don't trust links (especially from low rep users).  Also, try putting simpler statements in the blocks to isolate the problem.  Try just `SELECT 1` then add a little more, etc, etc.

Comment: I did. You should now see it with the updated imjur link in my post. @MatBailie

Comment: Even with the entire query being "IF 1 THEN END IF" it will throw the same DDL error. @MatBailie

Comment: What is your Db2-server platform (z/os, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows) and Db2-server version?  What tool are you using to submit the anonymous block, or is this snippet part of an SQL-function or stored-procedure? Are you delimiting the block with BEGIN... END as compound-SQL required?  Your question is NOT COMPLETE without these basic facts.

Comment: Is there more code 'TRUE' always = 'TRUE'  hence the else portion is dead code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can’t ‘select to nowhere’ in a compound statement in DB2. Db2 CLP can return you the result set of a single sql statement, but it doesn’t try to do the same for select statements in a compound statement.
If you want to print the result set from a select statement in a compound statement, you can, for example, declare a cursor, fetch it in a loop, and use [dbms_output.put_line](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053539.html) calls to print the values of variables.